# Is it possible to create a Recurrent Neural Network with EncogModel?

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, encog

EncogModel is extremely useful thanks to its use of VersatileMLDataSet and the ability to perform cross validation.

However I can't see a way to create an Elman, Jordan or other RNN. Is this possible using EncogModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EncogModel does not support recurrent neural networks.  It would be a decent change to make it do this, because recurrent neural networks are time-series, the EncogModel class would need to be extended to support sequences.